# Null values not being returned in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in Postgresql, which I need to perform the union taking the null values, to add other values in another column of the junction.

Table one:
I filtered by date, because this data is generated daily and I only need the `current_date`
[image]

Table two: All names.

[image]

In table two I have 9 names that are not found in table one.
When I try to perform the join, I only get the 9 names from table one as a result.
Trying with date from table one to `current_date`
[image]

But if I don't filter the date from table one, the null value is returned.
That is, the name that is in table two but not in table one.
[image]

What I need is to join the two tables and where there is no asset referring to the second table, fill it with 0 (zero).
In this part I understood that I must use `COALESCE(vcm.ativo,0)`.
But first I need the names of the second table to appear as well.
The result should be like this:

[image]

If someone could help me, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Edited title as ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551  and sample data is also better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: You need to move filters on the inner table into the join condition. Filtering by date after the join won't work.

Comment: You could also use a CTE to modularize it and filter rows prior to the join: `with todays_data as (select * from T2 where date = <today>) select * from T1 left outer join todays_data on ...`

Comment: @shawnt00 I didn't understand how to put your comment in the query.
first because it is T1 that has a date.
I assume that <today> = current_date
But what about after "on..."?
Reference " on T1.cooperativa = T2.name" ?

I tried:
with todays_data as
(select vcm.cooperative, vcm.active
  from sga_bi.veiculos_coop_mensal as vcm
  where date = current_date)
  select name
  from sga.cooperativas as coop
  left outer join sga_bi.veiculos_coop_mensal as vcmm
  on coop.name = vcmm.cooperativa

This way returned all T2.name but 780 lines.
That is, not only today's T-1 data.

Comment: Got it!
It works now.
What i done:
with todays_data as 
(select vcm.cooperativa, vcm.ativo
 from sga_bi.veiculos_coop_mensal  as vcm 
 where data = current_date) 
 select coop.nome, COALESCE(vcmm.ativo,0)
 from sga.cooperativas as coop 
 left outer join todays_data as vcmm 
 on coop.nome = vcmm.cooperativa

Comment: The first option would have been `left outer join on coop.nome = vcmm.cooperativa and data = current_date`. The key is the compound condition with both included in the join logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment by the asker, the solution turned out to be

```
with todays_data as (
    select vcm.cooperativa, vcm.ativo 
    from sga_bi.veiculos_coop_mensal as vcm 
    where data = current_date
)
select coop.nome, COALESCE(vcmm.ativo,0) 
from sga.cooperativas as coop 
left outer join todays_data as vcmm 
on coop.nome = vcmm.cooperativa
```